# exporting summaries in single excel sheet

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function which can save multiple tables in xl file one by one but there should be a one row gap between tables .

I tried two ways but nothing is working perfectly as required.

```
library(expss)
library(openxlsx)

tt <- list()

tt[[length(tt)+1]]  = mtcars %>% 
  cross_cpct(
    cell_vars = list(cyl, gear),
    col_vars = list(total(), am, vs)
  )


tt[[length(tt)+1]] = mtcars %>%
  tab_cols(total(), am %nest% vs) %>%
  tab_cells(mpg, hp) %>%
  tab_stat_mean() %>%
  tab_cells(cyl) %>%
  tab_stat_cpct() %>%
  tab_pivot()


brands = as.sheet(t(replicate(20,sample(c(1:5,NA),4,replace = FALSE))))
score = sample(-1:1,20,replace = TRUE)
var_lab(brands) = "Used brands"
val_lab(brands) = autonum("
Brand A
Brand B
Brand C
Brand D
Brand E
")

tt[[length(tt)+1]] <- cro_cpct(mrset(brands), score)

wb1 <- createWorkbook()

tabl_theme <- function(tbls, wb){
  addWorksheet(wb, "Tables")
  rows <- c(0, cumsum(2 + sapply(tbls, nrow)[-length(tbls)])) + 1
  setColWidths(wb, 1,cols = 1:100, widths = "auto")
  for(i in seq_along(tbls)){
    xl_write(tbls[[i]],wb,1,row = rows[i])
  }
  return(wb)
}

tabl_theme(tbls=tt,wb=wb1)
saveWorkbook(wb1, "test3.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
file.show("test3.xlsx")
```

I also tried to save like below but this also doesn't work do we have any other solution or what i am doing wrong.

The objective is to save n number of tables in tt, so i have more than 500 list of tables in tt and i want to save them in xlsx file with xl_write format only. also there should be one row gap between all the tables.

```
saving_tabls <- function(tbls, wb){

addWorksheet(wb, "Tables")

start_col <- 1
cols_between_data <- 3 

for(i in length(tbls)) {
  xl_write(xt[[1]],wb,1,row = start_col)
 }
  start_col <- start_col + nrow(xt[[1]]) + cols_between_data

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your desired format. Code below works for me:

```
wb1 <- createWorkbook()
sheet <- addWorksheet(wb1, "Tables")
setColWidths(wb1, sheet ,cols = 1:100, widths = "auto")
xl_write(tt, wb1, sheet)
saveWorkbook(wb1, "test3.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image: One row gap between tables]

Comment: as i will have many tables in list so i tired this way also . generally i had more than 500 tables. and this approach gets stuck whilse saving xlsx file . and took more than 45 minutes to save the tables . so i tried to modify little bit.

Comment: @user14176250 `saveWorkbook` takes 45 minutes or `xl_write`?

Comment: and after modifiying tabl_theme and saving_tabls function , its taking very less time but they are not giving a blank row row between tables.

Comment: @GregoryDemin  yes it took 45  minutes for saving 988 list of tables in xlsx file  with xl_write

Comment: @coder2learn Try `xl_write(tt, wb1, sheet, format_table = FALSE)`. Will it take as much time as with formatting?